# In React Admin, how to show SimpleFormIterator's first item by default so users do not have to click the add button the first time?

Tags: react-admin

This is the component:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/SimpleFormIterator.html

I want the first item to be required, and the user shouldn't be able to delete it.

As far as I understand, there is no built-in way for this component to do this, at this point.

I am wondering if there is a way to create a custom wrapper for this component, that can do this. Maybe render the first item separately within this custom wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the first item by default, you can set the default value to an empty array of objects.

```
<ArrayInput
   source="address"
   label="address"
   defaultValue={[{}]}
   ></ArrayInput>
```